# Multi dimensional dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, dictionary

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
from collections import defaultdict
from collections import Counter

new_dic_defaultdict = defaultdict(dict)
#new_dic_defaultdict = defaultdict(int)

file="SMSCDR_POSTPAID_150901235000_10.84.0.29_AS.log"

fp=open(file,"r")
str = fp.readlines();

for line in str:
        array = line.split('|')
        system_id = array[55]
        Origin = array[12]
        TIME = array[0]
        message_id = array[62]
        new_dic_defaultdict[Origin][system_id] = new_dic_defaultdict[Origin].setdefault(system_id, 0) + 1;

print new_dic_defaultdict
```

Here I can write two dimensional directory. If I add third dimension its not working.

```
Ex: new_dic_defaultdict[Origin][system_id][message_id] = new_dic_defaultdict[Origin][system_id].setdefault(message_id, 0) + 1;
```

How to solve this

Answer (score 0):

You can use defaultdict like that:

```
new_dic_defaultdict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
```

Comment: new_dic_defaultdict[Origin][system_id][message_id][lfr] = new_dic_defaultdict[Origin][system_id][message_id].setdefault(lfr, 0) + 1;

If i use that its working for three dimension. But not working for four dimension.

Comment: If you want more dimensions you can add them in similar way: new_dic_defaultdict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))). But it's not readable at all, so I would recommend you to use something like https://github.com/mewwts/addict